# Discord.py set user id as an argument

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a command where its using an user id as an argument after ctx to make the bot send the user mention. The problem is, i dont know whats the syntax for user id. Im already looking through the documentation but didnt find the answer there.

Heres the code.

```
@client.command()
async def userid(ctx, member: discord.Member.id):
    await ctx.send(f'{member.mention})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there.

The typehint converts usernames, mentions, ID and display_name into a Member object, this object contains all of the above.

```py
@client.command()
async def userid(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await ctx.send(member.mention)
```

Comment: Since the syntax apply for both mention and id, how to make the command only apply for id and ignoring mention argument?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Okay here, so when i type the command, the member itself apply for id and mention, example the bot prefix is "!" and i wrote !userid "user id" there, its worked, and using !userid "@user" it works also, i actually want the command only accepting id as an argument and not mention. Is there any way i can make the bot ignore the command when the user type the command with the user mention and not from id.

Comment: There may be a way but it would be messy and not ideal, the whole point is that member is a Member object which contains all of that information. The type hint auto converts the member ID into a Member object.

Comment: Oh i see, okay then.