# Discord name = discord ID, how to find it?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have a problem. I can only unban members only by their discord ID (@username
doesn't work!) I can't unban people with @username. Is there a command like `@username = Discord profile id or sth`? How can I fix it? This is my code:

```
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    @commands.has_guild_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def unban(self, ctx, member, *, reason="xyz"):
        member = await self.bot.fetch_user(int(member))
        await ctx.guild.unban(member, reason=reason)
        await ctx.channel.send(f"***{member.mention}xyz***")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py set user id as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646719/discord-py-set-user-id-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey so if you want to get id of someone with ping I got you. A ping is equal to:

```
<@user_id>
```

This is a command to get id from ping:

```
@client.command()
async def get_id(ctx, user_to_get_id):
    user_to_get_id = user_to_get_id.replace("<",""
    user_to_get_id = user_to_get_id.replace("@","")
    user_to_get_id = user_to_get_id.replace(">","")
    await ctx.reply(str(user_to_get_id))
```

So you can use this code to add to the unban command.