# Ho to get exactly id from ping discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a command using id from pinged user and the return id like that : `<@696986678887317556>` and i want it : `696986678887317556`, so i have coding this :

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def autp(ctx, name):
    print(name)
    name = str(name)
    nachar = ["@", "<", ">"]
    for x in nachar:
        id = name.replace(x, '')
    print(id)
```

And the result are this :
`<@696986678887317556`
how i can code it pls

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py set user id as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646719/discord-py-set-user-id-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned user will be in `ctx.message.mentions` so loop that or get the first item in the list, and you will find the first mention with also the id that doesen't contained special characters.

Answer (score 1):

Instad of `id` variable you can use `name` variable like that:

```
    nachar = ["@", "<", ">"]
    for x in nachar:
        name = name.replace(x, '')
    print(name)
```