# I create a bot in discord, but the function does not work because of the lack of arguments state and data

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.7, chatbot

I'm new to python and have taken on the task of creating a discord bot. Everything is going well, except for the function to kick the participant out. The code doesn't work because this function has no state and data arguments. I would be very grateful if someone could help.

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands

config = {
    'prefix': '.',
}

intents = discord.Intents().all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=config['prefix'], intents=intents)

@bot.event

async def on_member_join(member):
    await member.send('Привет! Добро пожаловать на наш сервер!')

@bot.command

async def kick(ctx, user : discord.User(), *arg, reason='Причина не указана'):
    await bot.kick(user)
    await ctx.send('Участник {user.name} был изгнан из сервера по причине "{reason}"')

bot.run(config['token'])
```

This is error that python returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Python\Projects\Discord\Revanius\main.py", line 20, in <module>
    async def kick(ctx, user : discord.User(), *arg, reason='Причина не указана'):
TypeError: BaseUser.__init__() missing 2 required keyword-only arguments: 'state' and 'data'
PS D:\Python\Projects\Discord\Revanius>
```

Help me please!

Comment: Please do not post your bot token online! You should regenerate it ASAP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord.py set user id as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646719/discord-py-set-user-id-as-an-argument)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is

```py
user: discord.User()
```

You're supposed to add a type annotation, but you're annotating it by creating an *instance*. Remove the round brackets `()` at the end of it.

If you want to read up on type annotations: https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/

Compare this to other languages, like for example Java:

```java
User user = ... // This is correct
new User() user = ... // This makes no sense
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you're looking for the method Member.kick().  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.kick

Comment: This is indeed wrong, but it's not the cause of the error message in the post.