# How do I mention someone in a slash command on discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I saw a lot of bots that requires an user mention, fetch through guild members while we type. And I have absolutely NO IDEA in how to let my bot show the users in the required field.  No need the be a big code, just an easy and simple way.

```py
@bot.hybrid_command(with_app_command=True) 
async def hug(ctx, user):
```

I want to my discord bot show me a list of user while I'm inputing their nicknames after
"/command-name `user:`"

Comment: Welcome to SO! To post here, you must have at least made an attempt to solve your problem. Multiple solutions can be found online by searching "discord.py user parameter". I even found a different [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646719/discord-py-set-user-id-as-an-argument) that answers this exact question.

Please remember next time to try and look up the solution to your problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: TY, @MrDiamond. I was searching like crazy to solve this, and I didn't manage to find the key words to find this. Can you post this link as answer so I can check as SOLVED ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the search term "discord.py user parameter", there are many resources that work just fine. Here is a different SO post that solves this exact problem.

[Discord.py set user id as an argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68646719/discord-py-set-user-id-as-an-argument)

Please remember to make an attempt at making the code before posting it to SO.

Comment: I did try, I'm not that kind of lazy who copy and paste codes. I just didn't managed to find the right part on the documentation.  But ty anyway

(And I need to learn better how to read documentations, some things doesn't even make sense to me)